# Parallax Left Side Number shows only on active Animated line section. only one number should be see at time

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parallax, scrollspy

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
      counter-reset: a;
    }
    
    .affix {
      top: 20px;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
    }
    
    div.col-sm-9 div {
      height: 550px;
      font-size: 28px;
    }
    
    .point {
      width: 30px;
      height: 2px;
      background: tomato;
      transition: width 1s ease;
      padding: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .active {
      background: blue !important;
      width: 50px;
      color: #000;
    }
    
    .point a:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      counter-increment: a;
      content: "0" counter(a);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 5px;
      transition: all .3s ease;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    
    #section1 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #1E88E5;
    }
    
    #section2 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #673ab7;
    }
    
    #section3 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ff9800;
    }
    
    #section41 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #00bcd4;
    }
    
    #section42 {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #009688;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
      #section1,
      #section2,
      #section3,
      #section41,
      #section42 {
        margin-left: 150px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="15">

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#2196F3;color:#fff;height:220px;">
    <h1>Scrollspy & Affix Example</h1>
    <h3>Fixed vertical sidenav on scroll</h3>
    <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix" and data-spy="scrollspy".</p>
    <p>The left menu sticks the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels, and the links in the menu are automatically updated based on scroll position.</p>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="col-sm-3" id="myScrollspy">
        <div class="indicate-dots ">
          <ul class="nav nav-stacked" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="205">
            <li class="point">
              <a href="#section1" style="padding: 0px; position: absolute; top:-9px; left:2px;"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="point">
              <a href="#section2" style="padding: 0px; position: absolute; top:-9px; left:2px;"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="point">
              <a href="#section3" style="padding: 0px; position: absolute; top:-9px; left:2px;"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="point">
              <a href="#section41" style="padding: 0px; position: absolute; top:-9px; left:2px;"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="point">
              <a href="#section42" style="padding: 0px; position: absolute; top:-9px; left:2px;"> </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div id="section1">
          <h1>Section 1</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
          <p>Parallax Left Side Number shows only on active Animated line section. only one number should be see at time and all the number are hide, except the active number. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="section2">
          <h1>Section 2</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section3">
          <h1>Section 3</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section41">
          <h1>Section 4-1</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section42">
          <h1>Section 4-2</h1>
          <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have added a Parallax Left Side Number and line which is fixed. lines are animated with every section. I want text should also animate with line. At a
   time only one number show with line and other numbers hide. i used scrollspy for parllex and css counter increment for number increment. the number are not animating with lines.

```
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5aaU.jpg
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please give me proper solution

Comment: Can any one help me to give answer?